# execute a code when attribute is missing or is set to true

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I have the following:

```
const test= {
  "_id": "global-config",
  "_rev": "9-3f62f1ebf8f5c829d14d3bb57c5d1a04",
  "resultDbsPurge": {
    "v": "v3",
    "status": true
  }
}
```

so in my code I check and whenever status is true or the status attr is missing I do some operation but the problem is exactly here:

```
if(test.resultDbsPurge.status){
      do some operations
  }
```

in the above code if status is true then the code works as expected however when the status is totally missing I need "do some operations" be executed. How can I do that in the right way?

Comment: `test.resultDbsPurge.status === undefined` would tell you that the property is not there, or it is there and it is weirdly set to the undefined value.  You could also `Object.keys(test.resultDbsPurge).includes('status')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the property exists in the object using the `in` operator. If the property do not exist, execute an action

Please take a look at the following example where the object's status property has been removed

```js
const test = {
  _id: "global-config",
  _rev: "9-3f62f1ebf8f5c829d14d3bb57c5d1a04",
  resultDbsPurge: {
    v: "v3"
  },
};

if (!('status' in test.resultDbsPurge)) {
  console.log('nami')
}
```

See

- [in operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in)